# Import python module from a GitHub repo that does not have setup.py

Tags: python

I want to import [OpenBulletToPython library from GitHub](https://github.com/Categorically/OpenBulletToPython) So how do I do that? When I tried using `pip install git+https://github.com/Categorically/OpenBulletToPython`, I receive an `ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project git+https://github.com/Categorically/OpenBulletToPython.` So how can I import it??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the repository you linked to does not have a setup script.
So, you basically have to options:

1. Copy & Paste the code into the project where you want to use it (check the license before you do this)
2. Fork the repository and add a setup script yourself (as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html))

Comment: there is no license in the repository. does it mean that I can copy paste it?

Comment: Well, you could also just fork it and do what you want with your fork. As long as you keep your changes public, you should be good to go. Or contact the author directly and ask if you’re allowed to copy it or raise an issue on GitHub asking for a license…